# Why am i not getting desired result?

Tags: java

```
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
    float val=(i/100);
    System.out.println(val);                    
}
```

Output:

```
0.0
0.0
0.0....
```

Desired Output:

```
0.0
0.1
0.2
0.3...
```

I am trying to convert percentage value between 0 to 100
why happened this?

Answer (score 2):

Since `i` & `100` are both integer values, the result of their division will also be an integer. Hence, you need to convert at least one of them (the division operands) to a `float`, & divide by **10** instead:

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++) // Change the loop step to 10 also
{
    float val = (float)i / 10; // or float val = i / (float)10;
    System.out.println(val);
}
```

Output:

```
0.0
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.7
0.8
0.9
```

Answer (score 1):

`i` and `100` are both integers, so will return an integer. You're dividing integers, which means that you're using integer division.

In integer division the fractional part of the result is thrown away.

Try doing this:

```
float val = (i / 100f);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the compiler is performing integer division on 2 integers, then casting the result (0) to a float. To avoid this, add an explicit cast to either side of your division. This will cast earlier and perform floating point division.

```
float val = (float) i / 100;

// output
0.0
0.01
0.02
0.03
...
```

Comment: You should provide more explanation

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the change as:

```
float val=(i/100f);
```

As of now you are dividing an int by an int  which returns and int and hence you are not getting the desired result.

Comment: No you can't . You need a explicit casting from double to float.  (i/100.0) will return a double value.

Comment: @SagarGandhi:- Thanks for pointing it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to divide `float` to get `float`, otherwise `int / int` just give an `int` and you are assigning it to a `float`.

```
float val=(Float.valueOf(i)/100);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is java promotion rules.
in the expression , (i/100) both are integer so result is integer,. 99/100 is o.99 , when converted to int it becomes 0.

According Java Language Specification (Numberic Promotion 5.6

```
Numeric  promotion  (§5.6)  brings  the  operands  of  a  numeric  operator  to  a common type so that an operation can be performed.

When an operator applies binary numeric promotion to a pair of operands, each of which must denote a value that is convertible to a numeric type, the following rules apply, in order:

1. If any operand is of a reference type, it is subjected to unboxing conversion
    (§5.1.8).

2. Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or both
    operands as specified by the following rules:
    • If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.
    • Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted to float.
    • Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other is converted to long.
    • Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int.
```

Answer (score 0):

The data types of `i` and `100` are integer in your expression. Integer Division `(int/int)` is computed as `Math.floor(int/int)` (equivalent operation) and it always returns zero in your case.

try using one of the following expresssions to convert atleast one of the operands to float or double.

`float val=(float)i/100` or
   `float val=i/(float)100` or
   `float val=i/100.0f`

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're doing integer division.

Divide by a double or a float, and it will work:

double scale = ( n / 1024.0 ) * 255 ;

Or, if you want it as a float,

float scale = ( n / 1024.0f ) * 255 ;

Or

float val=(float)i/100; // covert i to float and divide